# set SYSROOT to NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

any one can say how to set **SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm** manually for ndk-build in windows.can any one help to solve this problem

Comment: What's your final goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can set platform as android-9 in file $NDK/build/core/add-application.mk
 just by replacing android-5 with android-9